# Error: Failed to query available provider packages; terraform init

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

```
terraform_1.0.11_windows_amd64\Terraform>terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "3.7.0"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: could not connect to
│ registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
│ (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵
```

what's wrong here; I am in the directory where the config file with .tf exists and user profile has right credentials

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like a network error, here is a debug checklist you can try:

- Accessing the terraform.json [URL](https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json) directly from the browser then the command line (wget/curl)
- Test with a diffrent computer on the same network
- Test in a different network

Hashicorp is using Fastly as a CDN and I already encountered corporate firewalls that blocked Fastly content unintentionally through a generic rule.